# Transition to and from position Auto

Tags: jquery, html, css

An element is arbitrarily placed on a page, and needs to transition to a fixed position on event (screen scroll in my case, but im using hover in the fiddle)

The original position of the element is centered withing a parent (top: auto and left: auto). On hover, it's supposed to smoothly move to the corner of the screen (left: 0, top: 0) and then comeback. Instead, it just jumps in place, ignoring the transition property.

I realize that none of the browsers support transition to auto, but was hoping to find some work around for this.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g1edbt0k/2/)

```
<div>
    <span>test</span>
</div>

div {
    border: 1px solid red;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 15px;
}
span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: blue;
    transition: all 1s;
    position: fixed;
    left: auto;
    top: auto;
}
div:hover span {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

PS. I'm hoping for a css only fix, but a solution with JQuery would work as well.

Comment: the issue is with your `left:auto;` and `right:auto;`. I'm looking into why specifically this may cause a transition override.

Comment: I'm hoping for a css fix, but a jquery solution will work as well

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in that modern browsers are unable to transition to 'auto'.  You can use CSS to achieve what you're looking for though.

In your example, you'll need to center by changing

```
top: auto;
left: auto;
```

to

```
vertical-align: top;
left: calc(50% - 25px);
```

Remove the top property from the span and span:hover and replace it with vertical-align.

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dcqd2cbk/1/)

Comment: How about top: 0? The item needs to attach to the top of the screen and then return to the original position withing the div. If the div is large enough to have a scroll, the original 'top' can't be set to a number.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you set a specific `top` and `left`? you have `span{position: fixed}` so in this case you always know about your `top`, `right`, `bottom`, `left` (relative to viewport).

so try with:

```css
div {
    border: 1px solid red;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 15px;
}
span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: blue;
    transition: all 1s;
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -25px; /*or transform: translateX(-50%) if you don't know the width of span*/
    top: 16px;
}
div:hover span {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin-left: 0; /*or transform: none if you don't know the width of span*/
}
```

```html
<div>
    <span>test</span>
</div>
```

You can change the `top` `left` as you which to achieve what you want.

[Here a jsfiddle example to play with](http://jsfiddle.net/Yandy_Viera/0f5qw7bm/1/)