# does div:after content actually modify width? My transition isnt working with it

Tags: javascript, html, css

Quick code (Not my actual code but it represents it):

```css
#myDiv {
background: black;
color:white;
float:left;
min-width:45px;
max-width:450px;
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
    
#myDiv:hover:after {
width: inherit;
content: " This should resize my div. transitioning the new width.";
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">Here</div>
```

I know this question might be too tricky because selectors are elements apart (or something like it, I havent gotten too deep into the subject), but I need help finding a work around for this (Javascript welcomed, JQuery too: I would rather not though, since Im not too friendly with heavy libraries for small things), if anyone has time its much appreciated.

If you want to see what Im trying to achieve, comment below and ill post my actual code.

Comment: **[This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19579514/2065039)** might be useful.

Comment: They don't work with the width there, top and opacity are different and Content doesnt affect them directly and it they can be added no matter what, my problem is similar but different. Good information on the subject tho!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that transition doesn't work when you go from or to a property with auto. Check this out [Transition to and from position Auto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31575484/transition-to-and-from-position-auto)

You can do some workaround to achieve what you want e.g:

```css
#myDiv {
background: black;
color:white;
float:left;
width:45px;
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
#myDiv:hover{
    width: 450px;
}
    
#myDiv:hover:after {
width: inherit;
content: " This should resize my div. transitioning the new width.";
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">Here</div>
```

But that depends on your markup and your needs so if this not helps, you can add more details to your question or best add your real code.

Comment: adding a height restraint to the div + your work-around solves it completely.
Thanks bro!. If no one else has an answer for this, I'll select it as the answer in a few.

Comment: I'm glad to help you.

Comment: If you add a height restraint to the div remember add `overflow: hidden` to `#myDiv`, you're not seeing the text overfowing because it has `color: white` if you change it you will notice.